# Как можно переделать шаблон кода из c++ на язык python

Tags: python, c++

Я самостоятельно изучал python, он показался мне более простым, но после поступления я узнал что мы учимся на c++

Я знаю, возможно будет не логично смешивать 2 языка, но хотелось бы узнать можно ли сделать костыли, чтобы можно было писать этот же самый код из питона, например привет мир, но на с++

```
print("Hello, world!")
```

на

```
cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
```

те

```
#include <iostream>

#define print    std::cout <<
#define end      << std::endl

int main()
{
    
    
    print "Hello world!" end; // вот к такой строчке я пришел
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вопрос, собственно, в чём? Вы ведь сами себе ответили.

Comment: Не выйдет. Сначала то, оно будет работать, но когда размер проги пойдёт на 10000+ строк...

Comment: Я знаю. Мне бы лишь "привет мир" написать синтаксисом питона, но чтобы он работал на с++

Comment: Ну так у вас последний кусок кода и есть то что вы хотите, это же рабочий пример. Только вот это похоже на детей, которые пишут русские слова английскими буквами, думая, что знают английский. Не страдайте ******* и учите язык нормально

Comment: Одна из детских болезней... Особенно часто, если верить некоторым статьям, болеют паскалисты, страдая всякими `#define begin {` :)

Comment: Ну а в С++  пользуйтесь `printf`.  Что  вам даст сокращение  имени функции на один символ?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И смех и грех

```
#include <iostream>

#define print(arg) std::cout << arg << std::endl;

int main()
{
    print("Hello world!")
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот это я и искал. Спасибо

Comment: @Максим, если Вы получили нужный Вам ответ, примите его, пожалуйста. Для этого есть галочка слева от ответа.